# Getting a reference to a specific WPF listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to programmatically get a reference to a specific WPF listbox based on a string set to the name of the listbox.  I am trying to finish off this bit of code:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
string cmn = (st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ToString().Remove(0, 5)).Remove(4, 3);
stringArray = processMethodName(cmn);
populateLists(stringArray[0], stringArray[1], lst_Ingredients);
```

My 'processMethodName' function returns a value for stringArray[2] which is set to 'lst_Ingredients' however I do not know how to implement it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What ListBox are you talking about? The WinForms ListBox, ASP.NET one or something totally different?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer.  Was frustrating due to the number of posts / links regarding refering to objects within a listbox.  Anyway, here's the line of code that I needed:

```
populateLists(stringArray[0], stringArray[1], (ListBox)FindName(stringArray[2]));
```